# Как вытащить коодинтаы из json?

Tags: java, android

Есть `String` содержащий вот такой Json:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "source": "www.gmapgis.com", "features": 
[{"type":"Feature","properties": {  "style": "#FF0000,5,1,#ff8800,0.4"   },
"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [[49.86686,40.40937],[49.86657,40.40917],[49.86733,40.40898],[49.86686,40.40937]]]}}]}
```

Как спарсить значения координат?

Comment: можно использовать например библиотеку `gson`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример как это сделать при помощи [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

```
class Coordinate {
   private double lat;
   private double lon;

   public Coordinate(double lat, double lon){
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lon = lon;
   }
}
```

Сам метод который парсит json

```
List<Coordinate> coordinateParser(String json) {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray coordArr = data.getJSONArray("features")
            .getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry")
            .getJSONArray("coordinates")
            .getJSONArray(0);

    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < coordArr.length(); i++) {
        double lat = coordArr.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(0);
        double lon = coordArr.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(1);
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(lat, lon));
    }

    return coordinates;
}
```

А вообще я бы советовал создать model object и при помощи [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) сериализовать это автоматически без дополнительных манипуляции.

Comment: спасибо!)очень понраился твой ответ